# Toggle Windows Visual Effects using the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, visual-effects

I have two cmd scrips that allow me to toggle my PC between "performance" and "quiet" modes, killing or relaunching some apps, switching power plans and so on.

I would like to make them also switch between visual effects settings, namely 
"Adjust for best performance" "Let Windows choose".
I tried `REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects /v VisualFXSetting /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f` and `REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects /v VisualFXSetting /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`, however the only thing, registry editing is achieving is changing the option picked in the setting GUI. Even the "Apply" button stays disabled. I tried logging off and even that doesn't apply the changes.

Is there a way to change the visual effects from a cmd script with a change being applied immediately? Something like `powercfg.exe /setactive`, but for the `SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe`? Maybe a small program, somebody designed specifically for that?

Answer (score 2):

There are two registry changes required for changing the visual effects options,
followed by logout or restart.

**VisualFXSetting**

This DWORD item is found at key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects`
and its values are:

- **0** (zero) for Let Windows choose what's best for my computer settings
- **1** for Adjust for best appearance settings
- **2** for Adjust for best Performance settings
- **3** for Custom settings, if the user changed individual
  visual effect settings.

**UserPreferencesMask**

This DWORD item is found at key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
and can have the following values:

- Let Windows choose what's best for my computer : `9E 1E 07 80 12 00 00 00`
- Adjust for best appearance : `9E 3E 07 80 12 00 00 00`
- Adjust for best Performance : `9E 12 03 80 10 00 00 00`
- Custom : The binary value of `1001ABC0 00D1EF10 00000G11` in the first 3 bytes

Each of the above letters ABCDEFG has the value 0=off and 1=on, as follows:

- A : Smooth-scroll list boxes
- B : Slide open combo boxes
- C : Fade or slide menus into view
- D : Show shadows under mouse pointer
- E : Fade or slide ToolTips into view
- F : Fade out menu items after clicking
- G : Show shadows under windows

References :

- [How to Change Visual Effects Settings in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6377-change-visual-effects-settings-windows-10-a.html)
- [How to Change the Visual Effects Settings in Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1908-visual-effects-settings-change.html)

Comment: I was kind of hoping for a way to achieve this without logging off, but well. I guess that's Windows for you/